# when I'm passing a invalid route name, instead of 404 status I'm getting the 405 response in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having a Asp.net core mvc application.

for post request when I'm passing a invalid url in a post call, its returning me 405 response instead of 404. any way to handle it.

I'M trying something like these, which is not working.

```
app.MapWhen(x=>x.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status405MethodNotAllowed, builder =>
            { 
                builder.UseStatusCodePages(ctx =>
              {
             if (ctx.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 405)
                 ctx.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;

               return Task.CompletedTask;
              });
                });
```

only first time application is hitting, how to verify these

Comment: You should be using x.Response.StatusCode instead of ctx.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode

Comment: inside statuscodePage() I don't have access to the x. Response.StatusCode